# How to control "Google Home" devices from node-red?

Tags: node-red

I have a variety of devices connected to Google Home, such as smart plugs, smart lights etc.

Is it possible to control these devices from Node Red, via Google Home?

E.g Node Red would tell Google Home to turn off "WashingMachineSmartPlug", and Google Home would then instruct the device to do just that.

I have found numerous resources on *adding* devices to Google Home via Node Red (e.g "Nora"), but I have yet to find a way to control existing devices already attached to Google Home.

Note:  I am aware it's possible to control such devices directly from Node Red-->TheDevice, I am asking if there is any way to control them via GoogleHome.

The reason for that is, we have a number of devices from a number of manufacturers - and having to implement the custom direct connection for each manufacturer into Node Red is time consuming and inelegant, compared to talking to a single control point that already exists.

Comment: There is addon https://www.home-assistant.io/integrations/google_assistant and also after digging some more I found this source https://github.com/i8beef/HomeAutio.Mqtt.GoogleHome Both are basically bridges, but the last option can be done offline.

Comment: Exactly what I was seeking, thankyou!

Comment: Glad to help. I'll add it as an answer then.

Comment: @MtlDev have you found a way to control Google Home devices? As far as I know there is no API to do that unless you implement a google assistant device and then you can send commands like "turn on X" to Google. I'm the creator of NORA and I would love to add that ability to NORA.